# In a modal what is the standard way to get image height after it is opened?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a modal to display a gallery of images.  When a thumbnail is clicked the full version of the image is displayed.  I need to determine the height of the image immediately after the modal is opened but I'm having trouble getting the correct value on the first click. On the second click my function returns the correct height.  What is the standard way to solve a problem like this?

**Example**

In the simplified example below a `"click" event` opens the modal and the `function measureHeight` gets the height property.  The first time I click the button it gives me a tiny number.  The second time I click the same button it gives me the correct number. I believe this is because the image is in the cache the 2nd time.

```
window.addEventListener("click", measureHeight);

function measureHeight() {
    var unitHeight = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('target')).height;
}
```

Comment: You need to preload the full-sized images, then you can get the height/width from the `HTMLImageElement`

Comment: Is there a way to do this without preloading?  That may be a lot of images that the user doesn't want to see.

Comment: If you have a server that returns the image url, you could also return the height/width of the image as well

Comment: Can I do that with Javascript?

Comment: Yes. How are you getting a list of images to show?

Comment: Maybe you are trying to get the height before it is displayed (is modal animating while displaying the image?). Try adding a 100ms delay before calling `measureHeight` function.

Comment: I don't necessarily compile a list to show.  I just call them as needed.  Is there a procedure for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to set the height/width without preloading the images would be to get a list of images from a server that also return height/width.

So, we would make a request to the server and display a thumb for each image.

Let's assume this is how the json is returned:

```
[
    {
        thumb: '/img/thumb/1.jpg',
        src: '/img/large/1.jpg',
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    },
    {
        thumb: '/img/thumb/2.jpg',
        src: '/img/large/2.jpg',
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    },
    {
        thumb: '/img/thumb/3.jpg',
        src: '/img/large/3.jpg',
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    }
]
```

We can then use this:

```
// Fetch a list of images and there info
let req = fetch('/get/image/list')
let json = await req.json()

// Loop through the resulting list of items
json.forEach(image => {
    // Create a thumbnail with attributes that describe the larger image
    let thumb = document.createElement('img')
    thumb.src = image.thumb
    thumb.setAttribute('orig-width', image.width)
    thumb.setAttribute('orig-height', image.height)
    thumb.setAttribute('orig-src', image.src)

    // Here is where we would add an event listener to the thumbnail
    thumb.addEventListener('click', e => {
        let clickTarget = e.currentTarget
        let width = clickTarget.getAttribute('orig-width')
        let height = clickTarget.getAttribute('orig-height')
        let src = clickTarget.getAttribute('orig-src')

        // Here is where you would resize
        let target = document.getElementById('target')
        target.style.height = height + 'px';

        // Next you load the image into the target
        let img = document.createElement('img')
        img.src = src
        target.appendChild(img)
    })

    // Finally add the clickable item to the document
    document.appendChild(thumb)
})
```

That is a decent method for setting height/width.

If you don't have a server, you will need to hand code the html elements and put the height/width data in manually. You can then get the thumbs like this (make sure to add the class to all the thumb images):

```
let thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('.thumb')
```

Comment: I have no problem hand coding the objects into a JSON file.  I'm testing this locally on my hard drive anyway.  Can I create a JSON file with the image data, place it in my root directory and then call it with JS?

Comment: I'm going to try the JSON file just to practice that concept because it sounds brilliant.  But I just realized that might not work in this particular situation.  My image uses, `width: 100%;  height: auto;` so it scales with the screen width.  I need to use `.getComputedStyle` because the height is dynamic.  Am I up against the wall on this one?

Comment: the json can return any height/width that you want. All that will do is set the size of the modal, so it doesn't have to be the size of the image if you don't want it to be.

Comment: Also note that you must be running on a web server to do ajax, so use xampp, wamp, etc. or just the basic chrome web server plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en